# Python edit specific words of a text file

Tags: python, file, text

My program is a basic Tkinter game with a scoreboard type system. This system stores the username and the number of attempts each user has had in a text file.

For example, when it is the user's first time, it appends their name to the end of the text file as   [joe_bloggs, 1] with joe_bloggs being the username and 1 being the number of attempts. As its the user's first time, it's 1.

I am trying to look for a way to 'update' or change the number '1' to increment by 1 each time. This text file stores all the users, i.e [Joe,1] [example1, 1] [example2, 2] in that format.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
write = ("[", username, attempts ,"]")

if (username not in filecontents): #Searches the file contents for the username    
    with open("test.txt", "a") as Attempts:    
        Attempts.write(write)
        print("written to file")  

else:
    print("already exists")
    #Here is where I want to have the mechanism to update the number.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MYGz Currently, they're separated by a space. Thanks

Comment: For your use case Mike's solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be using the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html?module-shelve) module of the standard library:

```
import shelve

scores = shelve.open('scores')
scores['joe_bloggs'] = 1
print(scores['joe_bloggs'])
scores['joe_bloggs'] += 1
print(scores['joe_bloggs'])
scores.close()
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Next session:

```
scores = shelve.open('scores')
print(scores['joe_bloggs'])
```

Output:

```
2
```

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. The difference with “dbm” databases is that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the pickle module can handle. This includes most class instances, recursive data types, and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects. The keys are ordinary strings.

You can convert the whole content into a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(scores)
{'joe_bloggs': 2}
```

Adapted to your use case:

```
username = 'joe_bloggs'

with shelve.open('scores') as scores:  
    if username in scores: 
        scores[username] += 1 
        print("already exists")
    else:
        print("written to file")  
        scores[username] = 1
```

If you don't always want to check if the user is already there, you can use a `defaultdict`. First, create the file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import shelve

with shelve.open('scores', writeback=True) as scores:
    scores['scores'] = defaultdict(int)
```

Later, you just need to write `scores['scores'][user] += 1`:

```
username = 'joe_bloggs'

with shelve.open('scores', writeback=True) as scores:  
    scores['scores'][user] += 1
```

An example with multiple users and increments:

```
with shelve.open('scores', writeback=True) as scores:
    for user in ['joe_bloggs', 'user2']:
        for score in range(1, 4):
            scores['scores'][user] += 1
            print(user, scores['scores'][user])
```

Output:

```
joe_bloggs 1
joe_bloggs 2
joe_bloggs 3
user2 1
user2 2
user2 3
```

Comment: I see. How is it different than pickle?

Comment: It is (like a) a dictionary.

Comment: This solution is more simpler IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) module to persist simple application states.